# Symbian: How can I convert Arabic Unicode

Tags: symbian

I receive via HTTP request, a TDesC8 Unicode string in Symbian C++, when I convert it via 
following function it doesn't change anything

HTTP request return:

```
TBuf8<300>buf;
buf.Copy(_L8("\u0627\u0646\u0627 \u0645\u0639\u0627\u0643"));
HBufC* temp = CnvUtfConverter::ConvertToUnicodeFromUtf8L(buf);
```

How can I convert a TDesC8 Unicode to a TDes16 in human readable form for Arabic language?

I'm using Symbian C++.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

line

```
_LIT8(KTest, "\u0627\u0646\u0627 \u0645\u0639\u0627\u0643");
```

was giving me

```
warning: character is out of range
```

As soon as I changed it to 
    _LIT16(KTest2, "\u0627\u0646\u0627 \u0645\u0639\u0627\u0643");

Everything compiled alright and some arabic chars were shown without any conversion. So I suppose \u0627 is already in UCS2 encoding not UTF8, no need to convert it.